# Haskell Function Application

Tags: haskell, function

A bit of a neophyte haskell question, but I came across this example in Haskell's [tutorial examples](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10).  For "find the last element of a list" there are some obvious versions, like

```
last' [x] = x
last' (_:xs) = last' xs
```

But I can't make sense of an alternate version presented:

```
myLast' = foldr1 (const id)
```

So, in trying to make sense of what the application of the id function is doing, I tried in ghci:

```
const id 1 2 -> gives 2
```

This binds like this:

```
(const id) 1 2 -> gives 2
```

And not like this:

```
 const (id 1) 2 -> gives 1
```

But I'm not making sense of this. `(const id)` should translate to something like

```
`(\x y->x) (\x->x)`
```

Shouldn't this return a function that simply returns the id of its first element? Or, how is the function order making (const id) behave differently than const?

Comment: Welcome to the 10k club!

Comment: I'd like to thank the academy, my producer, the director ....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The definition of `const` is

```
const x = \_ -> x
```

Hence, `(const id)` is a function which takes one argument and always returns `id` and

```
const id 1 2 = (\_ -> id) 1 2
             = id 2
             = 2
```

The definition of `foldr1` is

```
foldr1 f [x] = x
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)
```

If we have

```
myLast' = foldr1 (const id)
```

then

```
myLast' [x] = foldr1 (const id) [x]
              {- definition of foldr1 -}
            = x
```

and

```
myLast' (x:xs) = foldr1 (const id) (x:xs)
                 {- definition of foldr1 -}
               = (const id) x (foldr1 (const id) xs)
                 {- definition of const -}  
               = (\_ -> id) x (foldr1 (const id) xs)
                 {- function application -}  
               = id (foldr1 (const id) xs)
                 {- definition of id -}  
               = foldr1 (const id) xs
                 {- definition of myLast' -}  
               = myLast' xs
```

which agrees with the definition of `last'`.

Comment: ahhh. Didn't make the connection of the const returning the function. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is a great explanation, and stepping through it I can see how it works. But is foldr1 (const id) really the idiomatic way to do a myLast function? The first example given seems way more clear...

Comment: I wouldn't say it's idiomatic... Haskell geeks enjoy working out how to express things in a "point-free" style, or purely in terms of folds. It becomes a kind of programming puzzle. The first version is much more clear.

Answer (score 9):

I rely heavily on `:t` when trying to understand Haskell.  In this case:

```
Prelude> :t const id
const id :: b -> a -> a
```

might have helped you see what was going on.

Comment: To clarify, ":t" is a command you can use in GHCI to print the type of an expression.